# feel warm and close to someone

Tags: phrase-choice

I have been in Canada for seven years. When I have time, I volunteer to help new immigrants in community centres. One of the immigrants said to this to me:

> I am happy that we are Vietnamese. I really feel warm and close when I talk with you.

I am still trying to improve my English. He said, "... feel warm and close ...". Does it make sense to say "I feel warm and close when ..."?

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why it wouldn't.

Example:

> I feel very cozy when I'm at your house.

You can use other adverbial phrases instead of *when*.

Example:

> I feel happy **every time** I see you.